# How to display error message in a Div of the current page using Jquery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a page for delivery. My problem as mentioned in the title is that How to display the error message in a div of the current page( say at the top of the form)

Below is my some of my HTML:

```
<div id="erroMsg"></div>
<form name="shipForm" action="#" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;
                <select name="P_COUNTRY">
                    <option value="AU stralia">Australia</option>
                    <option value="New zealand">New zealand</option>
                    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                    <option value="US">US</option>
                    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                    <option value="other">other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <input type='submit' id="ship" name="submit" value='Next' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function isNull(ele) {
    var _form = document.shipForm;
    if (_form[ele].value == "") {
        _form[ele].focus();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function checkForm() {
    var _form = document.shipForm;
    if (isNull("P_COUNTRY")) {
        $("#erroMsg").html("x Select Country").css("color", "red").css("fontSize", "10px").show();
        _form.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works for me, however, the content of the message flashes and disappears very quickly. 
What I want is actually that to write the message in the `div`. But since that I redirect my page to current, after refreshing, it's gone, How to avoid this?
Or should I use jQuery? And How?

Comment: post full html code, and what redirect are you talking about ?

Comment: Consider using ´document.getElementsByName("shipForm")´ or ´$("[name='shipForm']")´ instead of the global variable ´document.shipForm´and consider using "id" instead, as "name" does not have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you have an error here:

```
_form.password.focus();
```

If there's no `.password` on `_form`, then `.focus()` will throw a TypeError, and prevent the `return false;` from  happening.

Remove that line, and it'll likely work.

Comment: WELL, GOOD TO know that, then in my case, I should put _form.P_COUNTRY.focus(); right?

Comment: @user2295136: If you want to focus that element, then it's worth a shot.

Comment: what should I put there: the name of the input, the id or the value?

Comment: @user2295136: The name. It doesn't have an ID anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
 <div id ="erroMsg"></div>
         <form name="shipForm" action ="#" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm()">
         <table>
        <tr><td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;
               <select name="P_COUNTRY">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="AU stralia">Australia</option>
        <option value="New zealand">New zealand</option>
        <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
        </select></td>
        <td align ="right"><input type='submit' id ="ship" name= "submit" value='Next'/></td>
        </tr></table>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            function isNull(ele) {  
                var _form = document.shipForm;  
                if (_form[ele].value == "") {  
                    _form[ele].focus();  
                    return true;  
                }  
                return false;  
            }  
            function checkForm(){  
                var _form = document.shipForm;
                if (isNull("P_COUNTRY")) {  
                    $("#erroMsg").html("x Select Country").css("color","red").css("fontSize","10px").show();  
                    return false;  
                } 
            }

    </script>
```